# Summing Multiple Records by Month

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sum

I want to sum checks to multiple vendors to produce a table giving vendor name, and 12 columns, one for each monthly total.

```
CHECK TABLE:
Vendor             Trans. Date    Amount
Able Mfg           2008-01-07     227.32
Acme Wolf Tails    2008-03-01      12.00
Able Mfg           2008-01-23     142.50

NEW TABLE:
Vendor            Jan     Feb     Mar     Apr    May ...
Able Mfg        369.82     0       0      0       0
Acme Wolf Tails                  12.00
```

Here's what I have so far.  I get the error, "Subquery returns more than one row":

```
select 
    `Pay To`,       
    MONTH(`Transaction Date`) AS `Trans Month`,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(`Charge Amount`)
        FROM `Check Table` 
        WHERE MONTH(`Transaction Date`) = 1
        GROUP BY `Pay To`) as `Jan`,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(`Charge Amount`)
        FROM `Check Table` 
        WHERE MONTH(`Transaction Date`) = 2
        GROUP BY `Pay To`) as `Feb`,
    (SELECT 
            SUM(`Charge Amount`)
        FROM `Check Table` 
        WHERE MONTH(`Transaction Date`) = 3
        GROUP BY `Pay To`) as `Mar`
FROM `Check table`
WHERE `Charge Amount` != 0
GROUP BY `Pay To`
ORDER BY `Pay To`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the following solution

http://davideguida.altervista.org/sql-generate-a-report-with-dynamic-columns-by-month/

Answer (score 0):

Chandan, I appreciate your time researching this.  I found an answer on the right side of the page:

```
SELECT
  `Pay To`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`Transaction Date`) = '01' THEN `Charge Amount` END) AS `Jan`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`Transaction Date`) = '02' THEN `Charge Amount` END) AS `Feb`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`Transaction Date`) = '03' THEN `Charge Amount` END) AS `Mar`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`Transaction Date`) = '04' THEN `Charge Amount` END) AS `Jan`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`Transaction Date`) = '05' THEN `Charge Amount` END) AS `May`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`Transaction Date`) = '06' THEN `Charge Amount` END) AS `Jun`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`Transaction Date`) = '07' THEN `Charge Amount` END) AS `Jul`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`Transaction Date`) = '08' THEN `Charge Amount` END) AS `Aug`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`Transaction Date`) = '09' THEN `Charge Amount` END) AS `Sep`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`Transaction Date`) = '10' THEN `Charge Amount` END) AS `Oct`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`Transaction Date`) = '11' THEN `Charge Amount` END) AS `Nov`,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(`Transaction Date`) = '12' THEN `Charge Amount` END) AS `Dec`
FROM `Check Table`
GROUP BY `Pay To`;
```

Thank you.